# Angular date() is not working in IE and Opera

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, date, formatting, opera

Why is this Angular code not working in IE and Opera?

```
{{ myDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy @ HH:mm:ss' }}
```

In Chrome and Firefox, the result is:

**28/03/2014 @ 19:16:55**

But in IE and Opera, the result is:

**NaN/NaN/0NaN @ NaN:NaN:NaN**

myDate corresponds with a `$scope.myDate` that contains a timestamp.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [filter date returns NaN-NaN-NaN in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23632059/filter-date-returns-nan-nan-nan-in-angularjs)

Comment: Thanks Paul, but I think it is not exactly the same problem, because I am using the Angular date filter instead doing my own directive and my problem is with IE, not Firefox. But still I will try to do something with the output format to check if it works.