# filter date returns NaN-NaN-NaN in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-scope

The filter I created below works on Chrome but not Firefox. I don't understand why.

```
  myApp.filter('dateCustom', [ '$filter', function ($filter) {
    return function (input) {

      // input => 2014-05-13 15:04:48 

      if(angular.isDefined(input)){
        var d = new Date(input);
        var time = d.getTime();
        return $filter('date')(time,'dd/MM/yyyy');
      }
    }
  }]);
```

HTML :

```
<span> {{ project.date_created_at | dateCustom }} </span>
```

Chrome

[image]

Firefox

[image]

Comment: what is the input value?

Comment: I still don't see the value just the object project.date_created_at which does not give us any clue of what is in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox doesn't support a date in that format, you will have to replace the dash's with slashes first.

```
var d = new Date(input.replace(/-/g, '/'));
```

Comment: Almost perfect ! You missed a `)`. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, quick copy/paste fail on my part. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Converting a string to date may vary from one browser to another. If you are getting something like `NaN` on your date's it is because of the Date conversion.

The best way I found is to use [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com), a great tool to formating dates. Effectively after I used it worked in every browser. Just using:

```
moment($scope.date).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
```